# Exporting a non public Type through public API

Tags: oop, warnings

I am trying to follow Trees tutorial at: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html
Here is the code I have written so far:

```
package trees.bst;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 *
 * @author sachin
 */
public class BinarySearchTree {

    Node root = null;

    class Node {

        Node left = null;
        Node right = null;
        int data = 0;

        public Node(int data) {
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    public void insert(int data) {
        root = insert(data, root);
    }

    public boolean lookup(int data) {
        return lookup(data, root);
    }

    public void buildTree(int numNodes) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
            int num = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            System.out.println("Inserting number:" + num);
            insert(num);
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return size(root);
    }

    public int maxDepth() {
        return maxDepth(root);
    }

    public int minValue() {
        return minValue(root);
    }

    public int maxValue() {
        return maxValue(root);
    }

    public void printTree() {   //inorder traversal
        System.out.println("inorder traversal:");
        printTree(root);
        System.out.println("\n--------------");
    }

    public void printPostorder() {   //inorder traversal
        System.out.println("printPostorder traversal:");
        printPostorder(root);
        System.out.println("\n--------------");
    }

    public int buildTreeFromOutputString(String op) {
        root = null;
        int i = 0;
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(op);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String stNum = st.nextToken();
            int num = Integer.parseInt(stNum);
            System.out.println("buildTreeFromOutputString: Inserting number:" + num);
            insert(num);
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public boolean hasPathSum(int pathsum) {
        return hasPathSum(pathsum, root);
    }

    public void mirror() {
        mirror(root);
    }

    public void doubleTree() {
        doubleTree(root);
    }

    public boolean sameTree(BinarySearchTree bst) { //is this tree same as another given tree?
        return sameTree(this.root, bst.getRoot());
    }

    public void printPaths() {
        if (root == null) {
            System.out.println("print path sum: tree is empty");
        }

        List pathSoFar = new ArrayList();
        printPaths(root, pathSoFar);

    }

    ///-------------------------------------------Public helper functions
    public Node getRoot() {
        return root;
    }
    //Exporting a non public Type through public API
    ///-------------------------------------------Helper Functions

    private boolean isLeaf(Node node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    ///-----------------------------------------------------------
    private boolean sameTree(Node n1, Node n2) {
        if ((n1 == null && n2 == null)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if ((n1 == null || n2 == null)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                if ((n1.data == n2.data)) {
                    return (sameTree(n1.left, n2.left) && sameTree(n1.right, n2.right));
                }
            }
        }

        return false;


    }

    private void doubleTree(Node node) {
        //create a copy
        //bypass the copy to continue looping
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }
        Node copyNode = new Node(node.data);
        Node temp = node.left;
        node.left = copyNode;
        copyNode.left = temp;
        doubleTree(copyNode.left);
        doubleTree(node.right);
    }

    private void mirror(Node node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }
        Node temp = node.left;
        node.left = node.right;
        node.right = temp;
        mirror(node.left);
        mirror(node.right);
    }

    private void printPaths(Node node, List pathSoFar) {
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }
        pathSoFar.add(node.data);
        if (isLeaf(node)) {
            System.out.println("path in tree:" + pathSoFar);
            pathSoFar.remove(pathSoFar.lastIndexOf(node.data)); //only the current node, a node.data may be duplicated
            return;
        } else {
            printPaths(node.left, pathSoFar);
            printPaths(node.right, pathSoFar);
        }
    }

    private boolean hasPathSum(int pathsum, Node node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return false;
        }
        int val = pathsum - node.data;
        boolean ret = false;
        if (val == 0 && isLeaf(node)) {
            ret = true;
        } else if (val == 0 && !isLeaf(node)) {
            ret = false;
        } else if (val != 0 && isLeaf(node)) {
            ret = false;
        } else if (val != 0 && !isLeaf(node)) {
            //recurse further
            ret = hasPathSum(val, node.left) || hasPathSum(val, node.right);
        }

        return ret;

    }

    private void printPostorder(Node node) {  //inorder traversal
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }
        printPostorder(node.left);
        printPostorder(node.right);
        System.out.print(" " + node.data);

    }

    private void printTree(Node node) {  //inorder traversal
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }
        printTree(node.left);
        System.out.print(" " + node.data);
        printTree(node.right);
    }

    private int minValue(Node node) {
        if (node == null) {
            //error case: this is not supported
            return -1;
        }
        if (node.left == null) {
            return node.data;
        } else {
            return minValue(node.left);
        }
    }

    private int maxValue(Node node) {
        if (node == null) {
            //error case: this is not supported
            return -1;
        }
        if (node.right == null) {
            return node.data;
        } else {
            return maxValue(node.right);
        }
    }

    private int maxDepth(Node node) {
        if (node == null || (node.left == null && node.right == null)) {
            return 0;
        }
        int ldepth = 1 + maxDepth(node.left);
        int rdepth = 1 + maxDepth(node.right);

        if (ldepth > rdepth) {
            return ldepth;
        } else {
            return rdepth;
        }
    }

    private int size(Node node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1 + size(node.left) + size(node.right);

    }

    private Node insert(int data, Node node) {
        if (node == null) {
            node = new Node(data);

        } else if (data <= node.data) {
            node.left = insert(data, node.left);
        } else {
            node.right = insert(data, node.right);
        }
        //control should never reach here;

        return node;
    }

    private boolean lookup(int data, Node node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (node.data == data) {
            return true;
        }
        if (data < node.data) {
            return lookup(data, node.left);
        } else {
            return lookup(data, node.right);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree();
        int treesize = 5;
        bst.buildTree(treesize);
        //treesize = bst.buildTreeFromOutputString("4 4 4 6 7");
        treesize = bst.buildTreeFromOutputString("3 4 6 3 6");
        //treesize = bst.buildTreeFromOutputString("10");
        for (int i = 0; i < treesize; i++) {
            System.out.println("Searching:" + i + " found:" + bst.lookup(i));
        }
        System.out.println("tree size:" + bst.size());
        System.out.println("maxDepth :" + bst.maxDepth());
        System.out.println("minvalue :" + bst.minValue());
        System.out.println("maxvalue :" + bst.maxValue());
        bst.printTree();
        bst.printPostorder();
        int pathSum = 10;
        System.out.println("hasPathSum " + pathSum + ":" + bst.hasPathSum(pathSum));
        pathSum = 6;
        System.out.println("hasPathSum " + pathSum + ":" + bst.hasPathSum(pathSum));
        pathSum = 19;
        System.out.println("hasPathSum " + pathSum + ":" + bst.hasPathSum(pathSum));
        bst.printPaths();

        bst.printTree();
       //bst.mirror();
        System.out.println("Tree after mirror function:");
        bst.printTree();
        //bst.doubleTree();
        System.out.println("Tree after double function:");
        bst.printTree();
        System.out.println("tree size:" + bst.size());

        System.out.println("Same tree:" + bst.sameTree(bst));
        BinarySearchTree bst2 = new BinarySearchTree();
        bst2.buildTree(treesize);
        treesize = bst2.buildTreeFromOutputString("3 4 6 3 6");
        bst2.printTree();
        System.out.println("Same tree:" + bst.sameTree(bst2));
        System.out.println("---");
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that netbeans shows Warning: Exporting a non public Type through public API for function getRoot().
I write this function to get root of tree to be used in sameTree() function, to help comparison of "this" with given tree. 
Perhaps this is a OOP design issue... How should I restructure the above code that I do not get this warning and what is the concept I am missing here?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand why you even created the getRoot() method. As long as you are inside your class you can even access private fields from any other object of the same class.

So you can change

```
public boolean sameTree(BinarySearchTree bst) { //is this tree same as another given tree?
    return sameTree(this.root, bst.getRoot());
}
```

to

```
public boolean sameTree(BinarySearchTree bst) { //is this tree same as another given tree?
    return sameTree(this.root, bst.root);
}
```

I would also add a "short path" for the case you pass the same instance to this method:

```
public boolean sameTree(BinarySearchTree bst) { //is this tree same as another given tree?
    if (this == bst) {
        return true;
    }
    return sameTree(this.root, bst.root);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that some code might call getRoot() but won't be able to use it's return value since you only gave package access to the Node class.

Make `Node` a top level class with its own file, or at least make it public

Comment: Intent here is not to expose Node here a it has no meaning for user of a tree class, how can we achieve this without exposing the Node class?

Comment: If you don't want to expose Node then mark getRoot() as private and the underlying implementation will be hidden to the user