# JUnit & warning exporting non public type through public api

Tags: java, junit, warnings

My unit test uses an enum as datapoints (see [JUnit Theories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Theories)).

This enum is only used in the test, therefore I prefer it to be encapsulated and a private nested class.  JUnit requires test methods to be public.  The test methods have the private enum as argument:

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
class ExampleTest {
    private enum Lists {
        EMPTY,
        SINGLE_ELEMENT,
        OTHER_ELEMENT,
        TWO_ELEMENTS;

        public Object createElements() {
            // Imagine createElements being abstract and 
            // implemented in each enum constant.
        }
    }

    @DataPoints
    public static final Lists[] ALL_LISTS = Lists.values();

    private List<Object> tested;

    @Theory
    public void add_sizeIncreased(Lists elementsToAdd) {
        int oldSize = tested.size();
        int nElementsAdded = elementsToAdd.size();

        tested.addAll(elementsToAdd);

        assertThat(tested.size(), is(equalTo(oldSize + nElementsAdded));
    }
}
```

This rightly causes the warning/hint: "Exporting non-public type through public API" (in Netbeans at least).

What is the correct way to solve this?

- I have not found a 'SuppressWarnings'-annotation for it;
- The answers to related SO questions [Sachin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659936/exporting-a-non-public-type-through-public-api), [Aselivanov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744851/exporting-non-public-type-through-public-api), and [user329820](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937589/exporting-non-public-type-through-public-api) argue that the warning is correct and that you should make the types public.  The unittest differs from these other situations in that the test's public methods are not called by any other code.
  *(I admit the testframework calls them, but I hope you see my point).*
- As far as I know, JUnit will not invoke private test methods, in fact it throws an error when it sees a private method annotated with 'Theory'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Just make the enum public. Since it is in test code it will not be exported in you jar / war so no big deal.
2. Accept an `Object` in your test method instead of `Lists` and cast.